# Attempting to use SQL-Developer to analyze a system table dump created with 'exp'

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-sqldeveloper, exp, imp

I'm attempting to recover the data from a specific table that exists in a system table dump I performed earlier. I would like to append the rows existing in the dump to any rows that may exist in the active table. The problem is, it's likely that the name of the table in the dump is not the same as what exists in the database currently (They're dynamically created with a prefix of ARC_TREND_). In addition, I don't know the name of the table as it exists in the dump, I was hoping to use SQL Developer to analyze the dump file as I can recognize the correct table by it's columns and it's existing rows.

While i'm going on blind faith that SQL Developer can work with my dump file, when attempting to open it, i'm getting a Java Heap OutOfMemory exception raised. I've adjusted the maximum heap size from 640m to 1024m in both sqldeveloper.bat and in sqldeveloper.conf, but to no avail.

Can someone recommend a course of action for me to take to recover the data from a table which exists in a exp created dump file? A graphical tool would be nice, but I'm no stranger to the command line. I need to analyze the tables that exist in the dump in order to pick the correct one out. Then I assume I can use `imp TABLE=` to bring it back into the active instance. It likely won't match the existing table name, so I will use SQL Developer to copy the rows from the imported table to the table where I need them to be.

The dump was taken from a Linux server running 10g, and will be imported to (the same server & database instance, upgraded) an 11g instance of the same database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're referring to `imp` rather than `impdp`, I assume this wasn't exported with data pump. Either way, I doubt you'll get anything useful through SQL Developer.

Fortunately most of what you're trying to do is quite easy from the command line; just run `imp` with the [`INDEXFILE` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10701/original_import.htm#sthref2219), which will give you a text file containing all the table (commented out with `REM`) and index creation commands. From that you should be able to spot the table from its column names.

You can't really see any row data though, so if there's more than one possible match you might need to import several tables and inspect the data in them in the database to see which one you really want.

Comment: Awesome. Indeed I did not export the data with expdp, just exp. I did some quick research while writing the script that performed the table dump and I understood exp & expdp to be identical aside from the method used to read and write data. I gather from your comment that they have more of a difference. I am going to try to identify the table via `INDEXFILE`. Thank you for the docs link.

Comment: The underlying engine is completely different, and the dump formats aren't interchangeable, and many parameters are different. The reason I womdered was that `impdp` allows you to rename things on the fly.